# edit URL of search result

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search

i have wordpress website with sailent theme
i have default search in header the result of search is `http://www.example.com/?s=colagen`
while "colagen" is the key that type it in search  but the result page don't look nice thats why i want search result url to be like this `http://www.exemple.com/?s=colagen&post_type=product`
because with this url the woocomerce product look better

Answer (score 0):

- you can add the extra url parameter with one simple jQuery line of code
- you can modify the search php template to match your needs

Comment: Can you help me with the jQuery line code ?